# Clicking a selector with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

So I am having trouble clicking a login button on the nike website..

I am not sure why It keeps crashing, well because it can't find the selector I guess but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I would like to also say I am having some sort of memory leak before puppeteer crashes and sometimes it will even crash my macbook completely if I don't cancel the process in time inside the console.

EDIT:
This code also causes a memory leak whenever it crashes forcing me to have to hard reset my mac if I don't cancel the application fast enough.

Node Version: 14.4.0
Puppeteer Version: 5.2.1

Current code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: ['--start-maximized']
    })

    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto('https://www.nike.com/')

    const winner = await Promise.race([
        page.waitForSelector('[data-path="join or login"]'),
        page.waitForSelector('[data-path="sign in"]')
    ])

    await page.click(winner._remoteObject.description)
})()
```

I have also tried:

```
await page.click('button[data-var]="loginBtn"');
```

Answer (score 7):

Try it:

```
await page.click('button[data-var="loginBtn"]');
```

Comment: In my case, the login button is on such a selector
'button[data-type="click_navJoinLogin"]'

Comment: Thanks to the answer above I am sure it has something to do with the A/B testing is why our selectors are different. :)

Answer (score 3):

They are [A/B testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A/B_testing) their website, so you may land on a page with very different selectors than you retreived while you visited the site from your own chrome browser.

In such cases you can try to grab the elements by their text content (unfortunately in this specific case that also changes over the designs) using XPath and its [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/contains) method. E.g. `$x('//span[contains(text(), "Sign In")]')[0]`

So I suggest to detect both button versions and get their most stable selectors, these can be based on data attributes as well:

**A**

```js
$('[data-path="sign in"]')
```

**B**

```js
$('[data-path="join or login"]')
```

Then with a [`Promise.race`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) you can detect which button is present and then extract its selector from the `JSHandle@node` like this: `._remoteObject.description`:

```
{
  type: 'object',
  subtype: 'node',
  className: 'HTMLButtonElement',
  description: 'button.nav-btn.p0-sm.body-3.u-bold.ml2-sm.mr2-sm',
  objectId: '{"injectedScriptId":3,"id":1}'
}
```

=>

```
button.nav-btn.p0-sm.prl3-sm.pt2-sm.pb2-sm.fs12-nav-sm.d-sm-b.nav-color-grey.hover-color-black
```

Example:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  defaultViewport: null,
  args: ['--start-maximized']
})
const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto('https://www.nike.com/')
const winner = await Promise.race([
  page.waitForSelector('[data-path="join or login"]'),
  page.waitForSelector('[data-path="sign in"]')
])

await page.click(winner._remoteObject.description)
```

FYI: Maximize the browser window as well to make sure the elment has the same selector name.

```
defaultViewport: null, args: ['--start-maximized']
```

Chromium starts in a bit smaller window with puppeteer by default.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for all the new information! I am still having trouble getting it to click, and I do see what you mean about the pages being different now I had not even noticed that before!

Comment: The promise is being rejected so I am guessing it is still having trouble finding the selectors?

Comment: Yes, it can be an A/B test with more than two UX iterations. Also make sure to maximize the browser window (if you haven't done it yet), you can avoid puppeteer loads the tablet version.

Comment: Yes, I've done exactly as you have in the example. I'll update the post to show the current code, the chromium window freezes for a second before a UnhandledPromiseRejection, TimeoutError throws an error in the console. Then I am able to close the window.

Comment: I suggest to open DevTools' Console once the exception is thrown and test if any of the two given selector works: `$('[data-path="join or login"]')` or `$('[data-path="sign in"]')`. If they return `null`, then inspect the actual _Sign/Log in_ button if it has a third `data-path`. Honestly for me it works like that, but it can also have localized content based on my IP adress, so it can differ what works for you.

Comment: @Blue have you been able to figure out what caused the issue?

Comment: No I am still having trouble i am also having a problem with it causing my whole 2019 macbook pro to crash.. I'm sure if a memory leak is happening or what. If I don't close application in time.

Comment: Like to the point where I can't even inspect the page.

Comment: I suppose `await Promise.race` is the culprit that leads to memory leak on Macs (in case of this specific website... otherwise it would be a well known problem. the puppeteer developers work on Mac as well). can you update your question with your Node.Js version, the exact puppeteer version and your exact OS as well? thanks (from now on I am not sure if I will be able to help, I am working from Windows environment and Ubuntu)

Comment: Well thank you for spending the time and trying to help I will update my post with the Node, and Puppeteer version now.

Comment: thanks for the infos. just an idea: if it is possible can you try it with Node.Js LTS version like 12.x? I can imagine it is not fully stable on all platforms with 14.x: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer#usage

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [{ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v5.3.0/docs/api.md#pagegotourl-options) with `page.goto`

This tells puppeteer to wait for the network to be idle *(no requests for 500ms)*

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        defaultViewport: null,
        args: ['--start-maximized']
    })

    const page = await browser.newPage()

    // load the nike.com page and wait for it to fully load (inc A/B scripts)
    await page.goto('https://www.nike.com/', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' })

    // select whichever element appears first
    var el = await page.waitForSelector('[data-path="join or login"], [data-path="sign in"]', { timeout: 1000 })

    // execute click
    await page.click(el._remoteObject.description)
})()
```

Comment: right. save me a lot